# Texture goes away when using the explosion modifier

Tags: texturing, modifiers, uv, objects

I've been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d59AouNM9lk   Which makes an object slowly dissolve with the explosion modifier. The only difference for me is that I have a texture on the object that is UV unwrapped. When I apply the explosion modifier, the texture goes away. How can I keep the texture on the object as it disintegrates?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. I didn't connect the textures to a texture coordinate node. Once I connected it to the object coordinate, the texture appeared again.